# How to I submit UTF-8 text to an extrinsic?

Tags: pallet, rust, data-type

I'm making a pallet that takes a string as the input. I tested it and it works well with English words, but when I try Vietnamese, the input box turned red and I couldn't submit the extrinsic. How can I solve this?
In my code, the data type I used to save the text is `Vec<u8>`

I[image]

Comment: Did you try to use `Bytes` there? ie `Viêt` -> `0x5669c3aa74`?

Comment: @ArturGontijo No (?), I don't quite understand what you mean. Can you explain further? I'd be very appreciative.

Comment: Posted it as an answer, let me know if I was clear there =).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use hex decimals (`0x...`) there too.

As you can see in its placeholder, when the `Bytes` field is empty:
[image]

So you will need a tool to convert your UTF8 string into bytes, like:

```
fn main() {
    println!("0x{}", hex::encode("Viêt"));
}
// Outputs: 0x5669c3aa74
```

Now you can fill the field with `0x5669c3aa74` and submit the extrinsic.

Comment: Thank you alot!

Comment: This would also work with emojis, right?

Comment: Yep, you can send a  as `0xf09f918d`.